# Adding css rules with text method to style element does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but does not work in IE8. Here is the html structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    // this does not work in IE
    $('<style type="text/css"></style>').text('body {margin: 0;}').appendTo('head');
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

And what' s the alternative to do this in IE?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand jquery selectors

Comment: But why it works in firefox and chrome?

Comment: @Jeremy, OP is passing an empty element to jQuery here to create a new element, not using a selector. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Just for reference on my previous point - the jQuery function can be used in quite a few ways - the way Powerboy is using it is documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is working for me in IE7:

```
$('<style type="text/css">body {margin: 0;}</style>').appendTo($('head'));
```

Another syntax which might be easier to read:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">body {margin:0;}</style>');
```

However, calling either `.text(val)` or `.html(val)` to set the contents of the `style` tag will cause an exception to be thrown because they set the `innerHTML` DOM property which is read-only.

Here is [IE's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(v=VS.85).aspx) of the `innerHTML` property:

> The property is read/write for all
>   objects except the following, for
>   which it is read-only: COL, COLGROUP,
>   FRAMESET, HEAD, HTML, STYLE, TABLE,
>   TBODY, TFOOT, THEAD, TITLE, TR.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with text and html in IE8.

Comment: @Ken Browning - Yes, I have already tried the same thing as your solution. It does work in IE8 and compatibility view. But I just think that <code>var rules = '100 letters here'; $('<style type="text/css"></style>').text(rules).appendTo('head'); </code> looks prettier than <code>var rules = '100 letters here'; $('<style type="text/css">' + rules + '</style>').appendTo('head'); </code>

Comment: You can choose pretty or working.  Up to you.  IE seems to think `innerHTML` should be read-only for `style` elements.

Comment: I'm using JQuery 1.4.1 with IE8 in standards mode and $('<style></style).text('...') will not work but $('<span></span).text('...').  I can't even append to a style element created like this.

Comment: "IE seems to think innerHTML should be read-only for style  elements". Maybe that is the point!

Comment: A digression: anybady know if there is a comprehensive collection of cross-browser issues (especially for the stupid IE) on the web? CSS hacks, JS hacks, etc. A comprehensive one!

Comment: .html() api takes care of the read only tags and does an append on them.. open up the jquery code and  look at the html function.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would do this.

```
var styles = {
  margin: '0',
  padding: '5px',
  border: 'solid 0px black'
}

$('body').css(styles);
```

Comment: ahh...this solution looks pretty! But if we need to apply multiple rules to different DOM elements, it will become wordy.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with a dependency plug-in for jQuery, just use this code:

```
$('head').append('<style>' + content + '</style>');
```

then your code will work in almost all browsers, here "content" is a variable you define externally and it will contain the data you want to insert into `<style>` tags. it will certainly work.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically load a CSS file using JQuery.

```
var link = $("<link>");
link.attr({
    type: 'text/css',
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: <your CSS file url>
});
$("head").append( link );
```

Comment: `$('<div>hello world</div>').appendTo($('body'));` will create a new div and append it to the body.  It's not a selector.

Comment: You solution is inserting a CSS file dynamically. But what I am looking for is an easy way to insert several (but not only one) CSS rules (not a CSS file) dynamically, since attaching another CSS file initializes another HTTP request. My program needs to run very fast and the server can be quite busy sometimes. I need to do everything to reduce the response time.

Comment: I'm not sure how long you think the http request will take, but as far as it goes, I don't believe loading all the CSS rules, and then NOT using them will be faster than getting the CSS file you'll need, unless you are looking at just a few CSS rules. How much CSS are we talking about?

Comment: Those CSS rules can be written in JS in advance, so they are transmitted in the same HTTP request with the JS file. I just want those CSS rules to apply to the webpage on demand.

Answer (score 1):

try:    `$('<div/>').load("style.css",function(style){
$(data.appendTo).append('<style type="text/css">' + style + '</style>');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `css` function in jQuery:

```
$( 'body' ).css( { margin: 0 } )
```

Comment: what if I need to append a lot of CSS rules? For example, I want to inject a whole CSS file into the HTML?

Comment: why don't you just insert it?
<link href="file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Because I want to insert some CSS rules on demand. In some cases the webpage does not need those rules if a user does not trigger an event. Attached an extra CSS file require another HTTP request.

Comment: @powerboy I could see that being a problem if you have a lot of things to add. You could do it all my way, but it would be a lot of find and replace! How many rules do you have?

Comment: I see, reference my answer to see how to insert a CSS file on demand.