# Access CKEditor iframe's style tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE8.

```
<div class="container">

<form action="">
  <textarea id="myed" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
</form>

<button id="twiddle">Twiddle CSS</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   CKEDITOR.replace('myed', {});
   $("#twiddle").click(function () {
       var oldstyle = $($($('#myed').parent().find('iframe')[0]).contents()[0]).find('style');
       $(oldstyle).append("body { background-color: red; }");
    });
 });
</script>
```

I expect it to turn the ckeditor's background red, which it does in FF/Chrome.  In IE, not only does it not do it, it throws an error:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 25 Jul 2011 20:52:27 UTC

```
Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 16
Char: 55208
Code: 0
URI: http://10.0.2.2:3000/javascripts/jquery.js?1297871725
```

jQuery: 1.5 CKEditor: 3.6.1

Comment: Interesting, this does work in IE: 

    $(oldstyle).after($("<style>body { background-color: red; }</style>"));

Comment: Since the method I suggested don't work for you, I think the problem may be the operations used to find the oldstyle. I think some of those jQuery calls could also be avoided. Could you paste the full html containing your textarea#myed, expecially its parents? So to try to find a better way to select it.

Comment: Hey David, what about doing `$('#myed').parent('body').css('background','red');` inside the `twiddle` click callback?

Comment: @stecb - nice idea, but this is all part of a live CSS editor thing, which takes the (css) text in a textarea and on keyup, sets the content of the <style> tags for 'real time' updates to the ckeditor contents.

Comment: or.. `$("<style type='text/css'> body{ background-color : red; } </style>").appendTo("head")`

Comment: I'd rather always use a class, anyway, instead of _fiddling_ with "raw CSS". On click, add a class to the iframe (then you can also easily remove it). My 2¢

Comment: that in your case would be `$("<style type='text/css'>"+ your css string inside textarea +"</style>").appendTo("head");`

Comment: stecb: bingo, looks like there is no alternative to including it as a string: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692770/style-style-textcss-appendtohead-does-not-work-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be easier to implement:

```
<textarea id="myed">body { background : red; }</textarea> <!-- here you will set your ckeditor -->

<button id="twiddle">update css</button>
```

and jQuery stuff:

```
$('#twiddle').click(function(){

    $('#customStyle').remove(); //if I already have set customStyle, remove it

    $("<style id='customStyle' type='text/css'>"+$('#myed').val()+"</style>").appendTo('head'); //add the new style to the current document head

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/67dXN/ or http://jsfiddle.net/67dXN/1/ (keyup, live updating)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `append` method meant to be used to insert DOM nodes as the last child of the specified element/s?

http://api.jquery.com/append

I think what you might be looking for is the `.html` method.

```
$(oldstyle).html( $(oldstyle).html() + " body { background-color: red; }" );
```

This way you will add new html to the one already present.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLfXB/3/ here you can see what I mean. If that doesn't work in your code, I think the problem is in that complex selector.