# jQuery text property and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(‘<style></style>’).text(‘css’).appendTo(‘head’) does not work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692770/style-style-textcss-appendtohead-does-not-work-in-ie)

I have this code:

```
$("head").append($("<style></style>")
  .attr("type", "text/css")
  .text("some text")
);
```

It works well with Firefox.

But with IE8, there is an error in the jQuery library:

> access to the method or properties unexpected

The problem happens when I add the text function (whatever the text is).

Comment: This post should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232557/jquery-css-write-into-the-style-tag

Comment: I want to add text inside the <style> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why don't you try this:

```
$("head").append($("<style></style>")
  .attr("type", "text/css")
  .html("some text")
);
```

---

#### Try this may be:

```
$( "<style>body { background: black; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" );
```

Comment: I tried : same problem.. its works with firefox but not IE... this founction uses innerHtml in the jquery library which was a problem just before using the jquery lines... IE has a problem with innerHtml

Comment: Did you try what Jay Blanchard said in comments?

Comment: it works thank you ... do you have any ideo why the previous lines do not work ?

Comment: It was because, `<style>` is not inside the `<body>` and jQuery can manipulate anything inside the body only.

Comment: @mlwacosmos see my answer below. PraveenKumar that's simply not correct.

Comment: @PraveenKumar "jQuery can manipulate anything inside the body only" is not correct. In IE, jQuery cannot manipulate everything inside the body.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is read-only for certain tags in IE - style is one of them. Here is a [well written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2692861/44816) to a similar question with sources.

Create your entire style block and append it to the head in one shot

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">some text</style>');
```