# Make table column dragable (sort) in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting

I designed a table in bootstrap and a list of column name. I want when I drag any column name in list or table column it will drag both.(table column and list li)

Check this link table column is dragable. When you drag table column it runs.

Go to your mouse table column name and drag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.table').dragtable();
  $('.list').dragtable();
});


(function($) {
  $.widget("akottr.dragtable", {
    options: {
      revert: false, // smooth revert
      dragHandle: '.table-handle', // handle for moving cols, if not exists the whole 'th' is the handle
      maxMovingRows: 40, // 1 -> only header. 40 row should be enough, the rest is usually not in the viewport
      excludeFooter: false, // excludes the footer row(s) while moving other columns. Make sense if there is a footer with a colspan. */
      onlyHeaderThreshold: 100, // TODO:  not implemented yet, switch automatically between entire col moving / only header moving
      dragaccept: null, // draggable cols -> default all
      persistState: null, // url or function -> plug in your custom persistState function right here. function call is persistState(originalTable)
      restoreState: null, // JSON-Object or function:  some kind of experimental aka Quick-Hack TODO: do it better
      exact: true, // removes pixels, so that the overlay table width fits exactly the original table width
      clickDelay: 10, // ms to wait before rendering sortable list and delegating click event
      containment: null, // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment, use it if you want to move in 2 dimesnions (together with axis: null)
      cursor: 'move', // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursor
      cursorAt: false, // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt
      distance: 0, // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-distance, for immediate feedback use "0"
      tolerance: 'pointer', // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance
      axis: 'x', // @see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis, Only vertical moving is allowed. Use 'x' or null. Use this in conjunction with the 'containment' setting
      beforeStart: $.noop, // returning FALSE will stop the execution chain.
      beforeMoving: $.noop,
      beforeReorganize: $.noop,
      beforeStop: $.noop
    },
    originalTable: {
      el: null,
      selectedHandle: null,
      sortOrder: null,
      startIndex: 0,
      endIndex: 0
    },
    sortableTable: {
      el: $(),
      selectedHandle: $(),
      movingRow: $()
    },
    persistState: function() {
      var _this = this;
      this.originalTable.el.find('th').each(function(i) {
        if (this.id !== '') {
          _this.originalTable.sortOrder[this.id] = i;
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: this.options.persistState,
        data: this.originalTable.sortOrder
      });
    },
    /*
     * persistObj looks like
     * {'id1':'2','id3':'3','id2':'1'}
     * table looks like
     * |   id2  |   id1   |   id3   |
     */
    _restoreState: function(persistObj) {
      for (var n in persistObj) {
        this.originalTable.startIndex = $('#' + n).closest('th').prevAll().size() + 1;
        this.originalTable.endIndex = parseInt(persistObj[n] + 1, 10);
        this._bubbleCols();
      }
    },
    // bubble the moved col left or right
    _bubbleCols: function() {
      var i, j, col1, col2;
      var from = this.originalTable.startIndex;
      var to = this.originalTable.endIndex;
      /* Find children thead and tbody.
       * Only to process the immediate tr-children. Bugfix for inner tables
       */
      var thtb = this.originalTable.el.children();
      if (this.options.excludeFooter) {
        thtb = thtb.not('tfoot');
      }
      if (from < to) {
        for (i = from; i < to; i++) {
          col1 = thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + i + ')')
            .add(thtb.find('> tr > th:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
          col2 = thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')')
            .add(thtb.find('> tr > th:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')'));
          for (j = 0; j < col1.length; j++) {
            swapNodes(col1[j], col2[j]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i = from; i > to; i--) {
          col1 = thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + i + ')')
            .add(thtb.find('> tr > th:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
          col2 = thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + (i - 1) + ')')
            .add(thtb.find('> tr > th:nth-child(' + (i - 1) + ')'));
          for (j = 0; j < col1.length; j++) {
            swapNodes(col1[j], col2[j]);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    _rearrangeTableBackroundProcessing: function() {
      var _this = this;
      return function() {
        _this._bubbleCols();
        _this.options.beforeStop(this.originalTable);
        _this.sortableTable.el.remove();
        restoreTextSelection();
        // persist state if necessary
        if (_this.options.persistState !== null) {
          $.isFunction(_this.options.persistState) ? _this.options.persistState(_this.originalTable) : _this.persistState();
        }
      };
    },
    _rearrangeTable: function() {
      var _this = this;
      return function() {
        // remove handler-class -> handler is now finished
        _this.originalTable.selectedHandle.removeClass('dragtable-handle-selected');
        // add disabled class -> reorgorganisation starts soon
        _this.sortableTable.el.sortable("disable");
        _this.sortableTable.el.addClass('dragtable-disabled');
        _this.options.beforeReorganize(_this.originalTable, _this.sortableTable);
        // do reorganisation asynchronous
        // for chrome a little bit more than 1 ms because we want to force a rerender
        _this.originalTable.endIndex = _this.sortableTable.movingRow.prevAll().size() + 1;
        setTimeout(_this._rearrangeTableBackroundProcessing(), 50);
      };
    },
    /*
     * Disrupts the table. The original table stays the same.
     * But on a layer above the original table we are constructing a list (ul > li)
     * each li with a separate table representig a single col of the original table.
     */
    _generateSortable: function(e) {
      !e.cancelBubble && (e.cancelBubble = true);
      var _this = this;
      // table attributes
      var attrs = this.originalTable.el[0].attributes;
      var attrsString = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
        if (attrs[i].nodeValue && attrs[i].nodeName != 'id' && attrs[i].nodeName != 'width') {
          attrsString += attrs[i].nodeName + '="' + attrs[i].nodeValue + '" ';
        }
      }

      // row attributes
      var rowAttrsArr = [];
      //compute height, special handling for ie needed :-(
      var heightArr = [];
      this.originalTable.el.find('tr').slice(0, this.options.maxMovingRows).each(function(i, v) {
        // row attributes
        var attrs = this.attributes;
        var attrsString = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < attrs.length; j++) {
          if (attrs[j].nodeValue && attrs[j].nodeName != 'id') {
            attrsString += " " + attrs[j].nodeName + '="' + attrs[j].nodeValue + '"';
          }
        }
        rowAttrsArr.push(attrsString);
        heightArr.push($(this).height());
      });

      // compute width, no special handling for ie needed :-)
      var widthArr = [];
      // compute total width, needed for not wrapping around after the screen ends (floating)
      var totalWidth = 0;
      /* Find children thead and tbody.
       * Only to process the immediate tr-children. Bugfix for inner tables
       */
      var thtb = _this.originalTable.el.children();
      if (this.options.excludeFooter) {
        thtb = thtb.not('tfoot');
      }
      thtb.find('> tr > th').each(function(i, v) {
        var w = $(this).outerWidth();
        widthArr.push(w);
        totalWidth += w;
      });
      if (_this.options.exact) {
        var difference = totalWidth - _this.originalTable.el.outerWidth();
        widthArr[0] -= difference;
      }
      // one extra px on right and left side
      totalWidth += 2

      var sortableHtml = '<ul class="dragtable-sortable" style="position:absolute; width:' + totalWidth + 'px;">';
      // assemble the needed html
      thtb.find('> tr > th').each(function(i, v) {
        sortableHtml += '<li>';
        sortableHtml += '<table ' + attrsString + '>';
        var row = thtb.find('> tr > th:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
        if (_this.options.maxMovingRows > 1) {
          row = row.add(thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').slice(0, _this.options.maxMovingRows - 1));
        }
        row.each(function(j) {
          // TODO: May cause duplicate style-Attribute
          var row_content = $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
          if (row_content.toLowerCase().indexOf('<th') === 0) sortableHtml += "<thead>";
          sortableHtml += '<tr ' + rowAttrsArr[j] + '" style="height:' + heightArr[j] + 'px;">';
          sortableHtml += row_content;
          if (row_content.toLowerCase().indexOf('<th') === 0) sortableHtml += "</thead>";
          sortableHtml += '</tr>';
        });
        sortableHtml += '</table>';
        sortableHtml += '</li>';
      });
      sortableHtml += '</ul>';
      this.sortableTable.el = this.originalTable.el.before(sortableHtml).prev();
      // set width if necessary
      this.sortableTable.el.find('> li > table').each(function(i, v) {
        $(this).css('width', widthArr[i] + 'px');
      });

      // assign this.sortableTable.selectedHandle
      this.sortableTable.selectedHandle = this.sortableTable.el.find('th .dragtable-handle-selected');

      var items = !this.options.dragaccept ? 'li' : 'li:has(' + this.options.dragaccept + ')';
      this.sortableTable.el.sortable({
        items: items,
        stop: this._rearrangeTable(),
        // pass thru options for sortable widget
        revert: this.options.revert,
        tolerance: this.options.tolerance,
        containment: this.options.containment,
        cursor: this.options.cursor,
        cursorAt: this.options.cursorAt,
        distance: this.options.distance,
        axis: this.options.axis
      });

      // assign start index
      this.originalTable.startIndex = $(e.target).closest('th').prevAll().size() + 1;

      this.options.beforeMoving(this.originalTable, this.sortableTable);
      // Start moving by delegating the original event to the new sortable table
      this.sortableTable.movingRow = this.sortableTable.el.find('> li:nth-child(' + this.originalTable.startIndex + ')');

      // prevent the user from drag selecting "highlighting" surrounding page elements
      disableTextSelection();
      // clone the initial event and trigger the sort with it
      this.sortableTable.movingRow.trigger($.extend($.Event(e.type), {
        which: 1,
        clientX: e.clientX,
        clientY: e.clientY,
        pageX: e.pageX,
        pageY: e.pageY,
        screenX: e.screenX,
        screenY: e.screenY
      }));

      // Some inner divs to deliver the posibillity to style the placeholder more sophisticated
      var placeholder = this.sortableTable.el.find('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
      if (!placeholder.height() <= 0) {
        placeholder.css('height', this.sortableTable.el.find('.ui-sortable-helper').height());
      }

      placeholder.html('<div class="outer" style="height:100%;"><div class="inner" style="height:100%;"></div></div>');
    },
    bindTo: {},
    _create: function() {
      this.originalTable = {
        el: this.element,
        selectedHandle: $(),
        sortOrder: {},
        startIndex: 0,
        endIndex: 0
      };
      // bind draggable to 'th' by default
      this.bindTo = this.originalTable.el.find('th');
      // filter only the cols that are accepted
      if (this.options.dragaccept) {
        this.bindTo = this.bindTo.filter(this.options.dragaccept);
      }
      // bind draggable to handle if exists
      if (this.bindTo.find(this.options.dragHandle).size() > 0) {
        this.bindTo = this.bindTo.find(this.options.dragHandle);
      }
      // restore state if necessary
      if (this.options.restoreState !== null) {
        $.isFunction(this.options.restoreState) ? this.options.restoreState(this.originalTable) : this._restoreState(this.options.restoreState);
      }
      var _this = this;
      this.bindTo.mousedown(function(evt) {
        if (_this.options.beforeStart(this.originalTable) === false) {
          return;
        }
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
        this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          _this.originalTable.selectedHandle = $(this);
          _this.originalTable.selectedHandle.addClass('dragtable-handle-selected');
          _this._generateSortable(evt);
        }, _this.options.clickDelay);
      }).mouseup(function(evt) {
        clearTimeout(this.downTimer);
      });
    },
    redraw: function() {
      this.destroy();
      this._create();
    },
    destroy: function() {
      this.bindTo.unbind('mousedown');
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments); // default destroy
      // now do other stuff particular to this widget
    }
  });

  /** closure-scoped "private" functions **/

  var body_onselectstart_save = $(document.body).attr('onselectstart'),
    body_unselectable_save = $(document.body).attr('unselectable');

  // css properties to disable user-select on the body tag by appending a <style> tag to the <head>
  // remove any current document selections

  function disableTextSelection() {
    // jQuery doesn't support the element.text attribute in MSIE 8
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692770/style-style-textcss-appendtohead-does-not-work-in-ie
    var $style = $('<style id="__dragtable_disable_text_selection__" type="text/css">body { -ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:-moz-none;-khtml-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none; }</style>');
    $(document.head).append($style);
    $(document.body).attr('onselectstart', 'return false;').attr('unselectable', 'on');
    if (window.getSelection) {
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    } else {
      document.selection.empty(); // MSIE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
    }
  }

  // remove the <style> tag, and restore the original <body> onselectstart attribute

  function restoreTextSelection() {
    $('#__dragtable_disable_text_selection__').remove();
    if (body_onselectstart_save) {
      $(document.body).attr('onselectstart', body_onselectstart_save);
    } else {
      $(document.body).removeAttr('onselectstart');
    }
    if (body_unselectable_save) {
      $(document.body).attr('unselectable', body_unselectable_save);
    } else {
      $(document.body).removeAttr('unselectable');
    }
  }

  function swapNodes(a, b) {
    var aparent = a.parentNode;
    var asibling = a.nextSibling === b ? a : a.nextSibling;
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    aparent.insertBefore(b, asibling);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
    .dragtable-sortable {

      list-style-type: none;

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

      -moz-user-select: none;

    }

    .dragtable-sortable li {

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

      float: left;

      font-size: 1em;

      background: white;

    }

    .dragtable-sortable th,

    .dragtable-sortable td {

      border-left: 0px;

    }

    .dragtable-sortable li:first-child th,

    .dragtable-sortable li:first-child td {

      border-left: 1px solid #CCC;

    }

    .ui-sortable-helper {

      opacity: 0.7;

      filter: alpha(opacity=70);

    }

    .ui-sortable-placeholder {

      -moz-box-shadow: 4px 5px 4px #C6C6C6 inset;

      -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 4px #C6C6C6 inset;

      box-shadow: 4px 5px 4px #C6C6C6 inset;

      border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

      visibility: visible !important;

      background: #EFEFEF !important;

      visibility: visible !important;

    }

    .ui-sortable-placeholder * {

      opacity: 0.0;

      visibility: hidden;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dragtable.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/akottr/dragtable/blob/master/jquery.dragtable.js"></script>
  <title>jquery.dragtable.js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="list">

    <li>FUNCTIONAL GROUP</li>
    <li>CALLS IN QUEUE</li>
    <li>LONG CALL WAITING</li>
    <li>SERVICE LEVEL</li>
    <li>AGENTS STAFFED</li>
    <li>Forecasted staff</li>
    <li>Longest Agent Available</li>
    <li>AGENTS AVAL</li>
    <li>AGENTS ON CALL</li>
    <li>Cumulative CALLS OFFERED</li>
    <li>Cumulative CALLS HANDLED</li>
    <li>Cumulative SERVICE LEVEL</li>
    <li>Cumulative CALLS ABND %</li>

  </ul>
  <table class="table dataTable tree" id="table-first" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle">
    <colgroup>
      <col id="col0">
        <col id="col1">
          <col id="col2">
            <col id="col3">
              <col id="col4">
                <col id="col5">
                  <col id="col6">
                    <col id="col7">
                      <col id="col8">
                        <col id="col9">
                          <col id="col10">
                            <col id="col11">
                              <col id="col12">
                                <col id="col13">
                                  <col id="col14">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="18%">FUNCTIONAL GROUP</th>
        <th width="5%">CALLS IN QUEUE</th>
        <th width="7%">LONG CALL WAITING</th>
        <th width="6%">SERVICE LEVEL</th>
        <th width="6%">AGENTS STAFFED</th>
        <th width="7%">Forecasted staff</th>
        <th width="8%">Longest Agent Available</th>
        <th width="5%">AGENTS AVAL</th>
        <th width="6%">AGENTS ON CALL</th>
        <th width="8%">Cumulative CALLS OFFERED</th>
        <th width="8%">Cumulative CALLS HANDLED</th>
        <th width="8%">Cumulative SERVICE LEVEL</th>
        <th width="8%">Cumulative CALLS ABND %</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!--START BILLING TABLE SECTION-->
      <tr class="treegrid-1 drill-parent">
        <td>BILLING</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>:57:12</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>984</td>
        <td>835</td>
        <td>86.79%</td>
        <td>15.14%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>BILLING-COX</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>:50:10</td>
        <td>80.50%</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>230</td>
        <td>79.23%</td>
        <td>2.80%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-2">
        <td>Payment</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>:50</td>
        <td>90.00%</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>230</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>1.00%</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="treegrid-66 treegrid-parent-62">
        <td>COLLECTIONS-SITEL</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-67 treegrid-parent-66">
        <td>SAINT CATH</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-68 treegrid-parent-67">
        <td>COLLECTIONS OPERATION</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-69 treegrid-parent-67">
        <td>COLLECTIONS</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-70 treegrid-parent-67">
        <td>TELEPHONE</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-71 treegrid-parent-66">
        <td>PANAMA</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="treegrid-72 treegrid-parent-71">
        <td>COLLECTIONS</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0:00:27</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>89.00%</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <!--END COLLECTIONS TABLE SECTION-->

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="table-responsive container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="dnd-moved">
                <th>Column #1</th>
                <th>Column #2</th>
                <th>Column #3</th>
                <th>Column #4</th>
                <th>Column #5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="dnd-moved">
                <td>Row #1-1</td>
                <td>Row #1-2</td>
                <td>Row #1-3</td>
                <td>Row #1-4</td>
                <td>Row #1-5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="dnd-moved">
                <td>Row #2-1</td>
                <td>Row #2-2</td>
                <td>Row #2-3</td>
                <td>Row #2-4</td>
                <td>Row #2-5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="dnd-moved">
                <td>Row #3-1</td>
                <td>Row #3-2</td>
                <td>Row #3-3</td>
                <td>Row #3-4</td>
                <td>Row #3-5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dragndrop.table.columns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $('.table').dragableColumns();
</script>
```

Demo page http://alexshnur.github.io/drag-n-drop-table-columns/